# IF statement inside FOR Loop returns false results

Tags: php, list, if-statement, for-loop, dropdown

I have a few days started studying PHP and i have the following code, which makes 3 check-boxes and 3 drop-down lists accordingly(could be more, that's not the issue).

The idea is that a custom MySQL query string will be created with more than one conditions. Drop-down lists will contain db fields. The user will decide how many custom conditions will add by clicking these check-boxes and setting a value in the drop-down list.

After clicking the submit button for every checkbox that is checked and if a value from the according drop-down box is set, the value from the drop-down list will be read. The code works and returns the correct results (values from drop-down lists) only if ALL or only the FIRST checkbox are/is checked. For example if the second or third checkbox is check and a value for the drop-down list is set, the if statement ignores it. Obviously there is something wrong with the if statement (in specific && condition) inside the for loop but can can fix it?. Additionally, if I just have only one condition in the if statement the results are correct!.

```
<?php
    echo <<<_query
    <form action="check_array.php" method="post">
    query1<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query0">
    query2<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query1">
    query3<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query2">

    fields0
    <select name="fields[]">
    <option selected value="null">Select field</option>
    <option value="author">author</option>
    <option value="title">title</option>
    <option value="category">category</option>
    </select>

    fields1
    <select name="fields[]">
    <option selected value="null">Select field</option>
    <option value="author">author</option>
    <option value="title">title</option>
    <option value="category">category</option>
    </select>

    fields2
    <select name="fields[]">
    <option selected value="null">Select field</option>
    <option value="author">author</option>
    <option value="title">title</option>
    <option value="category">category</option></form>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="check"></form>
    _query;

    for ($i=0;$i<3;++$i)
    {
        if (isset($_POST["query"][$i]) && $_POST["fields"][$i] !="null")
        {
            echo $_POST["query"][$i] ."<br>".$_POST["fields"][$i]."<br>";
        }
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't submit anything for checkboxes that are unchecked and so the array indexes for `query[]` are being thrown off any time there is a gap in the sequence of selected checkboxes. You can fix this by specifying the array indexes for your checkboxes.

Change

```
query1<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query0">
query2<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query1">
query3<input type="checkbox" name="query[]" value="query2">
```

to

```
query1<input type="checkbox" name="query[0]" value="query0">
query2<input type="checkbox" name="query[1]" value="query1">
query3<input type="checkbox" name="query[2]" value="query2">
```

Comment: Asaph: thank you very much for your quick and accurate response . This fixed the issue!.Very good to know.

Comment: @georgepgs You are welcome. Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Also, I would appreciate an upvote too.

Comment: My reputation is still to low for an upvote to count but says it has been recorded though